# Tab issue in iOS - cn1

Tags: codenameone

I have a tab component in a screen. If I select the last tab and scroll horizontally a bit then scroll vertically, the component stucks. I've tested it in iphn 6 plus and iphn x.

Look at the video [here](https://youtu.be/cJtwli0CTxg)

Comment: I'll need to understand the layout of the screen specifically the parents of the tabs components...